# Range based sort key dynamoDb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Recently I was working on a task in which I had data with `id_field`, `start-date` and `end-date` and `entity-obj` and needed to fetch results for a particular id whose `start-date` and `end-date` would lie in between current time (time of query) in dynamodb.

In my approach I used `id_field` as partition key and `end-date` as sort key and used filter to get entries with

```
start-date > current time.
```

Does any one have any approach where this problem can be solved by only querying without using filter expression?

Comment: 'without using filter expression' - what were you thinking of? you're practically filtering the data?

Comment: No, at this time DynamoDB doesn't support these types of queries since you can only use one index at a time. So either way you have to filter, either on the server using FIlterExpression or in the client after you retrieve the results. This might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76828194/how-can-i-efficiently-query-dynamodb-for-a-start-and-end-date-between-a-given-d/76847801#76847801

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB only supports a single attribute as a sort key. For that reason you should store the timestamp which will return the bulk of the data as sort key, then use a FilterExpression to obtain the correct results.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html